# PlotStyle with various operations

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[x2 = x /. FindRoot[Tan[x] - x, {x, x1}]; {x2 + x1, 2 x2 + x1}, {x1, 1, 15},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

It is a simple example of performing operation as well as plotting. In my case i want findroot operation to be done inside the plot command.  How can i manage plotstyle then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Plot[
  Evaluate[
   x2 = x /.
     FindRoot[Tan[x] - x, {x, x1}];
   {2 x2 + x1, x2 + x1}],
  {x1, 1, 15},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{"2\[ThinSpace]x2\[ThinSpace]+\[ThinSpace]x1", 
     "x2\[ThinSpace]+\[ThinSpace]x1"},
    {0.25, 0.75}]] //
 Quiet
```

[image]

Using [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) enables plotting; however, numerous error messages and plotting artifacts are produced. The plotting artifacts are due to the equation having multiple solutions. The first several positive solutions are

```
x /. NSolve[{Tan[x] - x == 0, 1 <= x <= 20}, x]

(* {4.49341, 7.72525, 10.9041, 14.0662, 17.2208} *)
```

**EDIT:** In general, trying to put everything inside the `Plot` statement may not be the best approach. Using an external function and `NSolve` instead of `FindRoot`

```
solns = x /. NSolve[{Tan[x] - x == 0, 1 <= x <= 30}, x];

sol[x1_?NumericQ] := Module[{min, max},
  {min, max} = {0.95, 1}*Nearest[solns, x1][[1]];
  x /.
   NSolve[{Tan[x] - x == 0, min <= x <= max}, x][[1]]]

Plot[
  Evaluate[
   x2 = sol[x1];
   {2 x2 + x1, x2 + x1}],
  {x1, 1, 15},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Exclusions -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{"2\[ThinSpace]x2\[ThinSpace]+\[ThinSpace]x1", 
     "x2\[ThinSpace]+\[ThinSpace]x1"},
    {0.25, 0.75}]] //
 Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: the solution of findroot is depending on x1 as tan[x]=x near x1 has separate solutions which depend on the value of x1.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `FindRoot`. `FindRoot[Tan[x] - x, {x, x1}]` will solve `Tan[x] - x == 0` for `x` starting with an initial estimate of `x1`. The result would be of the form `{x -> numeric value}` That rule will have no effect in `x1 /. rule` since there is no `x` to be replaced.

Comment: sir, i understand. there is a typo there, it should be  Table[x /. FindRoot[Tan[x] - x, {x, x1}], {x1, 1, 15}].  I ran this simple line to calculate various solution, the solution is indeed dependent on the x1.